# Why are named tuples always tracked by python's GC?

Tags: python, garbage-collection

As we (or at least I) learned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19391648/keeping-large-dictionary-in-python-affects-application-performance/19391867#19391867) simple tuples that only contain immutable values are not tracked by python's garbage collector, once it figures out that they can never be involved in reference cycles:

```
>>> import gc
>>> x = (1, 2)
>>> gc.is_tracked(x)
True
>>> gc.collect()
0
>>> gc.is_tracked(x)
False
```

Why isn't this the case for [namedtuple](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple)s, which are a subclass of tuple from the collections module that features named fields?

```
>>> import gc
>>> from collections import namedtuple
>>> foo = namedtuple('foo', ['x', 'y'])
>>> x = foo(1, 2)
>>> gc.is_tracked(x)
True
>>> gc.collect()
0
>>> gc.is_tracked(x)
True
```

Is there something inherent in their implementation that prevents this or was it just overlooked?

Comment: I believe the reason is simply because `nametuple` is not a built-in class. I.e. the GC is doing an explicit check for `tuple` during its cycle, it does **not** check for immutable types with only immutable elements(which is hard to check in the general case). Note that subclassing `tuple` does *not* imply immutability.

Comment: The referenced post says the GC "special cases" certain objects. I imagine it's a direct check against the tuple type. As the post says, doing this special casing is a tradeoff. In each case, there's a cost associated with even checking for the potential exemption. But the GC designers attempt to make decisions that trade a small up front payment for a long term win. Doing an introspective "is it a subclass of tuple" would be a bit more expensive than just "is it a tuple". Since tuples have a high frequency, it pays off, but NamedTuples aren't likely to be as frequent.

Comment: @TravisGriggs The performance issue is not in the checking of "is `tuple` subclass". The problem is that a `tuple` subclass *can* be mutable, hence the whole "is a tuple subclass" is completely meaningles for the GC. You should do an "is_immutable_object" generic check, which is *really* expensive (if at all possible) and then check that all contained objects are immutable. It's *much* easier to simply special case some built-in types that give some clear and simple guarantees on their immutability.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The only comment about this that I could find is in the `gcmodule.c` file of the Python sources:

> **NOTE:** about untracking of mutable objects.
>          Certain types of container cannot participate in a reference cycle, and    so do not need to be tracked by the garbage collector.
>   Untracking these    objects reduces the cost of garbage collections.
>   However, determining    which objects may be untracked is not free,
>   and the costs must be    weighed against the benefits for garbage
>   collection.
>
> There are two possible strategies for when to untrack a container:
>
> 1. When the container is created.
> 2. When the container is examined by the garbage collector.
>
> Tuples containing only immutable objects (integers, strings etc,
>   and    recursively, tuples of immutable objects) do not need to be
>   tracked.    The interpreter creates a large number of tuples, many of
>   which will    not survive until garbage collection. It is therefore
>   not worthwhile    to untrack eligible tuples at creation time.
>
> Instead, all tuples except the empty tuple are tracked when
>   created.     During garbage collection it is determined whether any
>   surviving tuples     can be untracked. A tuple can be untracked if all
>   of its contents are     already not tracked. Tuples are examined for
>   untracking in all garbage     collection cycles. It may take more than
>   one cycle to untrack a tuple.
>
> Dictionaries containing only immutable objects also do not need to
>   be    tracked. Dictionaries are untracked when created. If a tracked
>   item is    inserted into a dictionary (either as a key or value), the
>   dictionary    becomes tracked. During a full garbage collection (all
>   generations),    the collector will untrack any dictionaries whose
>   contents are not    tracked.
>
> The module provides the python function `is_tracked(obj)`, which
>   returns    the *current* tracking status of the object. Subsequent
>   garbage    collections may change the tracking status of the object.
>   Untracking of certain containers was introduced in issue [`#4688`](http://bugs.python.org/issue4688), and     the algorithm was refined in response to issue [`#14775`](http://bugs.python.org/issue14775).

(See the linked issues to see the real code that was introduced to allow untracking)

This comment is a bit ambiguous, however it does *not* state that the algorithm to choose which object to "untrack" applies to generic containers. This means that the code check only `tuple`s ( and `dict`s), not their subclasses.

You can see this in the code of the file:

```
/* Try to untrack all currently tracked dictionaries */
static void
untrack_dicts(PyGC_Head *head)
{
    PyGC_Head *next, *gc = head->gc.gc_next;
    while (gc != head) {
        PyObject *op = FROM_GC(gc);
        next = gc->gc.gc_next;
        if (PyDict_CheckExact(op))
            _PyDict_MaybeUntrack(op);
        gc = next;
    }
}
```

Note the call to `PyDict_CheckExact`, and:

```
static void
move_unreachable(PyGC_Head *young, PyGC_Head *unreachable)
{
    PyGC_Head *gc = young->gc.gc_next;

  /* omissis */
            if (PyTuple_CheckExact(op)) {
                _PyTuple_MaybeUntrack(op);
            }
```

Note tha call to `PyTuple_CheckExact`.

Also note that a subclass of `tuple` need not be immutable. This means that if you wanted to extend this mechanism outside `tuple` and `dict` you'd need a generic `is_immutable` function. This would be *really* expensive, if at all possible due to Python's dynamism (e.g. methods of the class may change at runtime, while this is not possible for `tuple` because it is a built-in type). Hence the devs chose to stick to few special case only some well-known built-ins.

---

This said, I believe they *could* special case `namedtuple`s too since they are pretty simple classes. There would be some issues for example when you call `namedtuple` you are creating a *new* class, hence the GC should check for a subclass.
And this might be a problem with code like:

```
class MyTuple(namedtuple('A', 'a b')):
    # whatever code you want
    pass
```

Because the `MyTuple` class need *not* be immutable, so the GC should check that the class is a *direct* subclass of `namedtuple` to be safe. However I'm pretty sure there are workarounds for this situation.

They probably didn't because `namedtuple`s are part of the standard library, not the python core. Maybe the devs didn't want to make the core dependent on a module of the standard library.

So, to answer your question:

- No, there is nothing in their implementation that inherently prevents untracking for `namedtuple`s
- No, I believe they did *not* "simply overlook" this. However only python devs could give a clear answer to why they chose not to include them. My guess is that they didn't think it would provide a big enough benefit for the change and they didn't want to make the core dependent on the standard library.

Answer (score 3):

@Bakunu gave an excellent answer - accept it :-)

A gloss here: No untracking gimmick is "free": there are real costs, in both runtime and explosion of tricky code to maintain. The base tuple and dict types are *very* heavily used, both by user programs and by the CPython implementation, and it's very often possible to untrack them. So special-casing them is worth some pain, and benefits "almost all" programs. While it's certainly possible to find examples of programs that would benefit from untracking `namedtuple`s (or ...) too, it wouldn't benefit the CPython implementation or *most* user programs. But it would impose *costs* on all programs  (more conditionals in the gc code to ask "is this a `namedtuple`?", etc).

Note that all container objects benefit from CPython's "generational" cyclic gc gimmicks:  the more collections a given container survives, the less often that container is scanned (because the container is moved to an "older generation", which is scanned less often).  So there's little *potential* gain unless a container type occurs in great numbers (often true of tuples, rarely true of dicts) or a container contains a great many objects (often true of dicts, rarely true of tuples).

Comment: I did accept @Bakunu's answer, but thank you for the additional insights into the gc :)