# Any reason why matplotlib animations would only work in interactive session?

Tags: python, macos, animation, matplotlib

If I create a file `test.py` with the code

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation

if __name__ == '__main__':
    fig = plt.figure()
    title = fig.suptitle("Test _")

    def anim(i):
        title.set_text("Test %d" % i)
        plt.plot([0,1], [0,1])

    FuncAnimation(fig, anim)
    plt.show()
```

and try to run it in my command line, using `python test.py`, I get an empty screen with the title `Test _` and without any axes.

The same is true when running with `python -i test.py`, but if I now enter the same code in the interactive session

```
>>> fig = plt.figure()
>>> title = fig.suptitle("Test _")
>>> FuncAnimation(fig, anim)
>>> plt.show()
```

everything just works as expected.

I have been looking at this for so long now and I don't seem to find any issues or questions that are related to this. I am using matplotlib 2.0.0 in python 3.5.2 on OS X.

Is this a (known) bug? Anyone with ideas why this might be happening or how this could be resolved?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [animation documentation](http://matplotlib.org/api/animation_api.html): "[..] it is critical to keep a reference to the instance object."

So you need to keep the FuncAnimation instance alive by assigning it to a variable.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation

if __name__ == '__main__':
    fig = plt.figure()
    title = fig.suptitle("Test _")

    def anim(i):
        title.set_text("Test %d" % i)
        plt.plot([0,1], [0,1])

    ani = FuncAnimation(fig, anim)
    plt.show()
```

---

There is an [ongoing discussion](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/1656) about whether the `Animation` should be stored internally or not.

Comment: I spent so much time there... Stupid that I didn't spot it. Thanks! PS: any idea why this might nevertheless work when in interactive mode (just out of curiosity)

Comment: By interactive mode you mean IPython console? In that case you simply don't loose the reference because the cell output is kept in memory.

Comment: No it's the python interpreter interactive mode. [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23843234/4375377) explains why the animation object is not garbage collected in my example...